# css-loader url() loads with `module.exports =`, Is there any options?

Tags: css, webpack, electron

I made some apps that wrapper some site with custom css. but image is not shown.

This is my webpack.config.js module part.

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['css-loader']               
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 1000000 // 1000kb
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Css look like this

```
.menu {
    background-images: url("images/menu.png");
}
```

Some of issue with jQuery and Security(External Sites!), I put `nodeIntegration: false` in webPreferences

```
const css = require('./foo.css');
// ..
webContents.insertCSS(css.toString());
```

but launch a app, image is not shown. in console, I got this background-images url

```
background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;png,bW9kdWxl //...
```

decode base64 result is

```
module.exports = "data:image/png;base64 //...
```

I think  `module.exports` cause this(Edit 3: `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` in console), because `nodeIntegration: false`

Is there any option to remove `module.exports =` in css-loader with other loaders? (or just turn `nodeIntergration` to `true`)?

It is same result on `file-loader`.

Edit 1: In my package.json: `"css-loader": "^0.28.7", "url-loader": "^0.6.2", "webpack": "^3.8.1"`

Edit 2: [Maybe cuase by this in `css-loader`?](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/8f1b57ce2d5aba6115d9b0f026dccdcb13f8b4aa/lib/localsLoader.js#L43)

Comment: Hi Hatson, I am concern about the `loader` you applied for images. I have used `file-loader` for image files

Comment: Yes, I know that, but this code is wirtten in when i just tried to `url-loader`. and `file-loader` retruns same result. `module.exports =` is in base64 string. different this is next of `module.exports =` and `module.exports` is not defined.

Comment: please try this: `use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=../images/&emitFile=false'` .

Comment: same result. `url(data:image/png;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydH //...` decode result is `module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "../ `. `module.exports` is not defined because `nodeIntegration: false`

Comment: I think that's an `electron` issue, can you take  a look at this pull request [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/345)

Comment: Or you can provide more information of your webpack